Vishnu's disguise as Jalandhara
I heard the Shiva Purana mentions the story of Vrinda (Tulasi) and Vishnu regarding the feud between Mahesha and Jalandhara Vishnu by his maya created a dream or illusion where Vishnu was shown tricking Vrinda as if he was Jalandhara. Do any Vaishnava puranas mention a similar act or did this trickery happen in real life as an act?
